# how to use variables outside of method

Tags: java, android

how do i pass char1 out of the onCreate method into another method -- in this case, pass it into selectChar2? Can i make char1 and char2 global or something? I'm not sure what's the proper way to go about this. please help!

```
private String char1,char2; // does this even do anything? I thought this would let me use char1 and char2 anywhere.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_char2);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String char1 = (String) extras.getString("char1"); //is the (String) necessary?

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.header);

        textView.setText(char1+" vs "+"char2");

    }


}

public void selectChar2(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button)v;
    String char2 = btn.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(PickChar2.this, DisplayMatchUp.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();

    extras.putString("Character1",char1); //char1 here is null...how do I get the value from the method above?
    extras.putString("Character2", char2);

    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: char1 & char2 are global already, which implies that they are available for referencing purposes in any part of your class, except for static methods

Comment: make them public for simplicity

Comment: @MocialovBoris Technically, `char1` and `char2` are *member* variables. Java doesn't have true global variables. However, your main point is still correct: they are available in both the `onCreate()` and `selectChar2()` methods.

Comment: No, the `(String)` is not needed since `getString()` returns a `String`. I strongly suggest that you become familiar with the API documentation at http://developer.android.com which provides this kind of information.

Comment: @MonadNewb I should be more careful with the use of such terms as: instance, global, member, field variables. Always use them interchangeably. I believe it is more language-specific terms rather than in theoretical cs

Comment: @MocialovBoris Personally, I use "instance", "member", and "field" all interchangeably. However, coming to Java from a C++ background, I have a different meaning associated with the word "global".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it is, you have declared and used two separate variables:

1. an instance variable: char1
2. a local variable: char1

1 is scoped to the class instance (it's accessible in any non-static scope within the class). 2 is scoped in the block where it is defined. in this case, simply don't create a local variable, and use the instance variable,

```
    char1 = (String) extras.getString("char1");
```

Comment: so, just to make sure i understood correctly. What I essentially did was overwrite the instance variable with the local variable? btw, what is an instance variable?

Comment: @user2498691 You may want to try some Java tutorials.

Comment: an instance variable is owned, or associated with the class instance. i wouldn't say you overwrote it. that would imply that there was one value and you changed it. you actually have two completely different variables. they outwardly appear to have the same name, but you have to consider the scope as well.

Answer (score 1):

You already declared the variables as global, but later you declared a local variable with the same name. The local variable will be used instead. To ensure that the global variable is used instead, use "this" keyword.

```
this.char2
```

refers to the global variable char2

```
char2
```

refers to the local variable char2

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make it public, or make it a parameter in both methods.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your program, you are creating a global variable `char1`...

```
private String char1,char2;
```

But in the `onCreate()` method, you have the following line...

```
String char1 = (String) extras.getString("char1");
```

The word *String* at the beginning of the line is creating a *Local* variable called `char1` which is separate to the global variable `char1` which you're creating at the top of your program.

You need to remove the `String` to simply be this...

```
char1 = (String) extras.getString("char1");
```

By doing this, you will now be assigning the value to the global variable at the top of your program, and can thus use it anywhere in this class that you wish.

Comment: what does the (String) part do?

Comment: In this case, nothing. This isn't strictly correct, but for learning purposes, the `(String)` bit is telling Java that the object is going to be a `String` - or, if its not given a `String`, it will try to change it to a `String`. However, calling `extras.getString();` already returns a `String` object, so in this case it isn't needed (but it isn't wrong either).